# Working with a MY_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m using jamie Rumbelow’s MY model as a way to better deal with my application.

```
https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model
```

The MY_model is the same except I have an added in variable for defining whether or not an item in the db is marked as being soft deleted or not.
protected $soft_delete_value = 3;

I only have that variable defined and have not altered his code yet to account for this value.

I have two things I want to do with this titles model that I need help understanding.

```
Titles Table - title_id, title_name, title_status_id
Title_Statuses_Table - title_status_id, title_status_name
```

What I want it to do is retrieve all of the rows that have a title_status_id of 1 and 2 and 3 because the soft delete value is different than the default set in the MY Model. What I would also like to have is instead of it returning the integer have it return the name of the status.

**Expected results:**

An array of objects that contain a title_id, title_name, title_status_name for which the titles have a status id of 1,2, or 3.

**Testing**

```
$titles = $this->titles_model->get_all();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($titles);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Actual results:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (`titles`)
WHERE `title_status_id` =  0

<pre>Array
(
)
```

**My Code**

```
class Titles_model extends MY_Model 
{
    /* --------------------------------------------------------------
    * VARIABLES
    * ------------------------------------------------------------ */

    /**
    * This model's default database table.
    */
    public $_table = 'titles';

    public $primary_key = 'title_id';

    /**
    * Support for soft deletes and this model's 'deleted' key
    */
    public $soft_delete = TRUE;
    public $soft_delete_key = 'title_status_id';
    public $soft_delete_value = 4;
    public $_temporary_with_deleted = FALSE;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Anybody else have any additional ideas/suggestions?

EDIT:

I've been tryign to figure this out all day and have hit a dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well here would be the function that you would need to get your expected result

```
      $this->db->select('
                titles.*,
                status.*,
                 ')
                ->join('status s', 'titles.title_status_id = s.title_status_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('titles.title_status_id', 1)
                ->or_where('titles.title_status_id', 2)
                ->or_where('titles.title_status_id', 3)
                ->from('titles')
                ->get()
                ->result_object();
```

Comment: Great answer. I just wonder if there's any simpler cleaner way to get this through the MY_Model.

Comment: thanks please give it a tick then please :) , sorry im not to familier with the version of CI that you are using there but hey sometimes you just have use the old methods now